# How do I compare cv.glmnet models with AIC?

Tags: regression, model-comparison, glmnet, elastic-net

I am using the `glmnet` package in R, and not(!) the `caret` package for my binary ElasticNet regression. I have come to the point where I would like to compare models (e.g. lambda set to `lambda.1se` or `lambda.min`, and models where `k-fold` is set to 5 or 10). But, I have not yet achieved to compute the `AICc` or `BIC` for my models. How do I do that? I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43746925/12546311) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/277205/290826) but it did not work for me, I only get an empty list.
Code:

```
set.seed(123)
foldid <- sample(rep(seq(10), length.out = nrow(x.train)))
list.of.fits.df <- list()
for (i in 0:10){
     fit.name <- paste0("alpha", i/10) 
     list.of.fits.df[[fit.name]] <- cv.glmnet(x.train, y.train, type.measure = c("auc"), alpha = i/10, family = "binomial", nfolds = 10, foldid = foldid, parallel = TRUE)
 }
best.fit <- coef(list.of.fits.df[[fit.name]], s = list.of.fits.df[[fit.name]]$lambda.1se)
best.fit.min <- coef(list.of.fits.df[[fit.name]], s = list.of.fits.df[[fit.name]]$lambda.min)

#AICc & BIC
#???
```

How do I find an `AIC` and/or `BIC` value from my `list.of.fits[[fit.name]]$lambda.min`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63171921/is-there-a-way-in-r-to-determine-aic-from-cv-glmnet we can create a function

```
cv_aicc <- function(fit, lambda = 'lambda.1se'){
  whlm <- which(fit$lambda == fit[[lambda]])
  with(fit$glmnet.fit,
       {
         tLL <- nulldev - nulldev * (1 - dev.ratio)[whlm]
         k <- df[whlm]
         n <- nobs
         return(list('AICc' = - tLL + 2 * k + 2 * k * (k + 1) / (n - k - 1),
                     'BIC' = log(n) * k - tLL))
       })
}
```

Plug in the lists now.

```
AICc <- cv_aicc(list.of.fits.df[[fit.name]])
AICc.min <- cv_aicc(list.of.fits.df[[fit.name]], 'lambda.min')
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking & answering your own question, but when the content of the answer originates in another source such as a book, article, or another webpage, it's only fair to provide a citation to that resource. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63171921/is-there-a-way-in-r-to-determine-aic-from-cv-glmnet